# DM9601 Driver for u-boot on beagleboard

Tags: usb, device-driver, beagleboard, u-boot, nic

I'm trying to do a nfs boot from my Beagleboard. My Davicom Dm9601, was not detected from u-boot, hence its failing with the error "0 ethernet devices found" and "Remote device not responded"

I have started writing the device-driver for the same.

1. dm9601_eth_before_probe
2. dm9601_eth_probe

With the above two functions its showing "1 Ethernet device found"

1. dm9601_init

When i'm trying to write above function, first action is to get the mac-address. I am taking asix.c given below as a reference. I've written read_cmd and write_cmd functions. But my current problem is i'm trying to using "Physical Address Register" register for reading the mac-address. I'm bit confused in the way the linux-drivers are working and asix.c is working.

Can anyone help me in understanding the same and how to go ahead in my implementation of the similar logic in dm9601 for u-boot.

References:

1. [linux-driver for dm9601](http://www.linux-arm.org/git?p=linux-2.6-stable.git;a=blob;f=drivers/usb/net/dm9601.c;h=4a932e1cd93bd39622e87715f75464a038154ac8;hb=d0374f4f9c35cdfbee0ade72d06732613b4e6628)
2. [u-boot driver of asix device](http://git.linaro.org/gitweb?p=boot/u-boot-linaro-stable.git;a=blob;f=drivers/usb/eth/asix.c;h=75ec8f78815b39810a68b3448193bc0bc7f19494;hb=b4eb22a60d15240d280785df7948448824d86fe5)
3. [Davicom DM9601 Datasheet](http://www.davicom.com.tw/big5/download/Data%20Sheet/DM9601-DS-P01-930914.pdf)

Comment: You should also get the Asix datasheet to better understand its device driver, and for comparison with the Davicom to properly determine what is really different and what is similar.

Comment: I have got that datasheet as well. They are trying to read using commands. But i'm not understanding how to do this with dm9601

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the MUSB host enable in config

Some times You need a little more time out setting of USB reset